# Failed to resolve: com.magnet.mmx:magnet-mmx-client-android:1.9.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

build.gradle(Project:)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.magnet.mmx:magnet-mmx-client-android:1.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
}
```

unable to resolve com.magnet.mmx:magnet-mmx-client-android:1.9.1  from build.gradle

build.gradle(Module:)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter{
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter{
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.magnet.com/artifactory/public"
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works fine

Answer (score 0):

In your app's `build.gradle`, use this,

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.magnet.com:8081/artifactory/public/"
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile('com.magnet.mmx:magnet-mmx-client-android:1.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

You can also find the dependency in this URL, 
http://repo.magnet.com/artifactory/public/com/magnet/mmx/magnet-mmx-client-android/1.9.1/